# How to detect overflow when subtracting two signed 32 bit numbers in C?

Tags: c, integer-overflow

I have got two signed integers, and I would like to subtract them. I need to know if it overflowed.

```
int one;
int two;
int result = two - one;

if (OVERFLOW) {
    printf("overflow");
} else {
    printf("no overflow");
}
```

Something like that. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: For simple overflow detection look at SEI CERT Coding Standard https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, overflow in signed calculations causes undefined behavior in C.

Secondly, forgetting about UB for a second and sticking to the typical overflow behavior of a 2's complement machine: overflow is revealed by the fact that result "moves" in the "wrong direction" from the first operand, i.e when the result ends up greater than the first operand with positive second operand (or smaller than the first operand with negative second operand).

In your case

```
int one, two;

int result = two - one;
if ((result < two) != (one > 0))
  printf("overflow");
```

Comment: If `int result = two - one;` overflows (or underflows) you're in Undefined Behaviour land and anything can happen.

Comment: Which is what stated explicitly in the very first sentence of my response. (Although the term "underflow" in its traditional meaning is not applicable here.)

Comment: I like this answer but as you noted - undefined behaviour.  If is safe to assume that the result will 'move' in the 'wrong direction'?

Comment: My point is that your `if` is not reliable. After the operation on the line before, if there was overflow, the result of the comparison is meaningless.

Comment: Well, I'm doing this under *assumption* (which I know is just an assumption) that this particular kind of UB typically manifests itself in practice as implementation-defined behavior and that a typical implementation on 2's complement machine "defines" it the way I expect it to be defined. I wouldn't use this trick myself on signed types (it is perfectly well defined on unsigned ones, BTW) in "functional" code, but rather restrict it to "assertion" code, i.e use it as a mere sanity check. As a sanity check this code is perfectly fine.

Comment: @pmg: Think of it as a solution specifically intended for implementations that *extend* C language specification by defining the signed integer overflow behavior in the way implied in my answer.

Comment: LOL ok. Assuming the behaviour is implementation-defined your answer is good ... for that implementation :)

Answer (score 15):

You need to catch the overlow (or underflow) **before** it happens. Once it happens you're in **Undefined Behaviour** land and all bets are off.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_invokes_UB(int a, int b) {
  int ub = 0;
  if ((b < 0) && (a < INT_MIN - b)) ub = 1;
  if ((b > 0) && (a > INT_MAX - b)) ub = 1;
  return ub;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("(INT_MAX-10) + 8: %d\n", sum_invokes_UB(INT_MAX - 10, 8));
  printf("(INT_MAX-10) + 100: %d\n", sum_invokes_UB(INT_MAX - 10, 100));
  printf("(INT_MAX-10) + INT_MIN: %d\n", sum_invokes_UB(INT_MAX - 10, INT_MIN));
  printf("100 + INT_MIN: %d\n", sum_invokes_UB(100, INT_MIN));
  printf("-100 + INT_MIN: %d\n", sum_invokes_UB(-100, INT_MIN));
  printf("INT_MIN - 100: %d\n", sum_invokes_UB(INT_MIN, -100));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your example is for unsigned integer. a-b > MAX and a-b < MIN will never give a > MAX -b, unless a + b > MAX.

Comment: @Jay-Pi: no, my example is for signed integer. Unsigned integer atithmetic doesn't, strictly speaking, cause UB. Suppose you're calculating Fibonacci numbers on a 8-bit computer: `0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89` now what??? If you calculate `55+89` you invoke UB (MAX being 127)... but you can test if it's safe `55 > 127 - 89`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 cases to consider on evaluating `a-b`:

1. `a-b` may underflow, iff `b>0 && a<0` and `a-b < min == a<min+b`
2. `a-b` may overflow, iff `b<0 && a>0` and `a-b > max == -b>max-a`

This leads us on simplifying the `a` case to

```c
#include <limits.h>

int sub_invokes_UB(int a, int b) {
  if ((b > 0) && (a < INT_MIN + b)) return 1; // error
  if ((b < 0) && (a > INT_MAX + b)) return 1; // error
  return 0; // ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with higher precision and compare.  Say you have 32-bit integers.  You can promote them to 64-bit integers, subtract, then compare that result with itself cast to 32-bit and then up again to 64 bits.

I wouldn't do it this way with `int`, because the language doesn't give you guarantees on sizes...  Maybe `int32_t` and `int64_t` from `<inttypes.h>` (from C99).

If you're on Windows use can use `ULongSub()` etc, which returns an error code on overflow.

Comment: If I do this case in 32 bit:
0x7fffffff - 0x80000000 = 0xffffffff
In 64 bit I get 0xffffffffffffffff
and thus i see no overflow (it should be, though. that's the wrong answer).

Answer (score -1):

https://llvm.org/doxygen/MathExtras_8h_source.html

```
/// Subtract two signed integers, computing the two's complement truncated
/// result, returning true if an overflow ocurred.
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<T>::value, T> SubOverflow(T X, T Y, T &Result) {
  #if __has_builtin(__builtin_sub_overflow)
    return __builtin_sub_overflow(X, Y, &Result);
  #else
    // Perform the unsigned addition.
    using U = std::make_unsigned_t<T>;
    const U UX = static_cast<U>(X);
    const U UY = static_cast<U>(Y);
    const U UResult = UX - UY;
 
    // Convert to signed.
    Result = static_cast<T>(UResult);
 
    // Subtracting a positive number from a negative results in a negative number.
    if (X <= 0 && Y > 0)
      return Result >= 0;
    // Subtracting a negative number from a positive results in a positive number.
    if (X >= 0 && Y < 0)
      return Result <= 0;
    return false;
  #endif
}
```

Comment: Not the person who downvoted but the question was in C and your answer is in C++.

Comment: Who said C++ in this question?